# Question in regards to how an O(N^3) looks like using while/for loops

Tags: big-o-notation

would the code below be considered O(N^3)?

```
while (...) {
   while (...) {
   }
   while (...) {
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking what do various $O(n^3)$ algorithms look like? There are plenty of reasons to have cubic upper bound on the number of operations, which may or may not manifest themselves in the structure of while/for loops.

Comment: It also depends on what $n$ is. If each loop is executed $n$ times at worst case then your algorithm is $O(n^2) $. But you can't tell just by looking ag the structure of the program